# What is the disk on NASA's anti-matter concept design?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, design, conceptual

On the concept art pictured in [this](http://www.nasa.gov/exploration/home/antimatter_spaceship.html) link, we see a very sleek looking ship that would supposedly be powered by antimatter.[image]

***What is the large disk present on the side of what appears to be the second stage division of the craft?***

Comment: That's the UCS (Unobtanium Collection System) antenna.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hehe

Comment: “I am having difficulty in maintaining contact with Earth. The trouble is in the AE-35 unit. My Fault Prediction Center reports that it may fail within seventy-two hours.”

Comment: No @OrganicMarble, that's the dilithium re-crystallization matrix.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "primarily opinion-based" because you cannot expect us to give a meaningful answer to the ideas the artist put into a drawing. You would have to ask him/her.

Comment: I am voting to leave it open, If I ask what that red, white and blue rectangle is near the nose of the ship it is reasonable to assume someone can answer without asking the artist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like a simplified drawing of a standard parabolic radio antenna.  Presumably pointed 'down' because the ship will be flying away from Earth.

[image]

<sup>Image produced for NASA's Exploration Office, Johnson Space Center (JSC) by John Frassanito and Associates</sup>

Comment: I wrote that because in the original image I couldn't see a curvature in the dish.

Comment: It's an *anti*dish.